# Laravel listen socket.io client emit

Tags: laravel, socket.io

I have chat application using Laravel + laravel-echo-server + Redis.
currently i am using http api request from client to send message. 
But its slow if i have large client number.
Is there a way to send message from client to server through socket and listen in laravel?

Probably something like this

```
    public function onMessage($client, $data)
    {
        .....
    }
```

i already tried laravel-websocket, but if i set APP_DEBUG=false in .env CustomSocketHandler unable to work anymore.
Thank you.